# php reload page when mysql dies

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to make this page reload when mysql dies so it will just keep running over and over as after a while the connection will die, timeout is my guess

Comment: better suggestion, run it with out time limits in the background.

Comment: i cant its shared hosting

Comment: @Dagon If it runs in the background, how will it show the results to the user when it succeeds?

Comment: When it gets an error, send an HTML page with `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="30; url=$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]">`

Comment: if its taking more than 30 seconds then no user want to sit there and wait, there are many ways to let them know when a background process finishes. if you replad the page, the displayed data is lost also

Comment: Maybe it's a kiosk, so there's no user waiting for it.

Comment: then there's no need for printing to screen; we can both only guess

Comment: I would be careful in trying to circumvent your host rules, such as running a script for longer than X can get you in trouble - just something to think about. perhaps you need to choose a more appropriate host.

Comment: ... and nobody has asked why this would be deemed an acceptable solution to your problem? :D

Answer (score 3):

Do like this, refresh after threee seconds...

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "", ""); 
if (!$link) {
    echo "Connection lost will refresh in 3 sec";
    header("Refresh: 3");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(header( "refresh:5;" ));
```